# Como posso fazer um controle de acesso, visualmente, em ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

Já consegui fazer a parte `gráfica(FRONT)`, entretanto estou com problemas na parte do código.

O controle de acessos funciona da seguinte forma: se o novo grupo(ou perfil) for criado, eu poderei decidir quais permissões ele vai possuir dentro do sistema, ou seja, se poderá ler,editar, criar ou deletar os CRUDS.

Problema: não sei como posso chamar esses métodos a partir de uma simples checkbox.

[image: A PARTE GRÁFICA :]

<sub>OBS: ESTOU USANDO O GERENCIADOR DE ADMINISTRAÇÃO ACTIVE_ADMIN</sub>

Aqui está o controlador do `active_admin` que cuida dessa parte de controle de acessos:

```html
ActiveAdmin.register ControleAcesso do
  permit_params [:grupo, :Noticium]

  controller do
    def i
      @noticia = Noticium.all
      @mural_atividades = MuralAtividade.all
      @minhas_atividades = MinhasAtividade.all
    end
  end

    index do
    column :grupo
    actions
  end
  
   form do |f|
    f.inputs "Controle de Acesso" do
           f.input :grupo, :label => 'Nome do Grupo'
        end

     tabs do 
      tab "Minhas Atividades" do
          f.inputs "Minhas Atividades" do
           f.input :Minhas_Atividades, as: :check_boxes, :collection => ['Criar', 'Visualizar', 'Editar', 'Deletar'], :label => 'Atividades'
         end 
       end

       tab "Mural de Atividades" do
         f.inputs "Mural de Atividades" do
           f.input :Mural_Atividades, as: :check_boxes, :collection => ['Criar', 'Visualizar', 'Editar', 'Deletar'], :label => 'Atividades'
          end
        end

        tab "Meu Perfil" do
          f.inputs "Meu Perfil" do
          f.input :Meu_Perfil, as: :check_boxes, :collection => ['Criar', 'Visualizar', 'Editar', 'Deletar'], :label => 'Perfil'
          end
        end

        tab "Notícias" do
          f.inputs "Noticias" do
          f.input :Noticium, as: :check_boxes, :collection => ['Criar', 'Visualizar', 'Editar', 'Deletar'], :label => 'Notícias'
          end
        end
      end
        f.actions
      end
end
```

Comment: Faltou descrever na pergunta quais são os problemas que você está encontrando.

Comment: é, pode ser kkk, tenho que esclarecer mais meus problemas...